# how to add flutter signup and login to unity AR project

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have created an AR app in unity and now I have to add login and signup page which I have created in flutter to my unity application can someone guide me!!.How I can do it?

Answer (score -1):

I am also currently integrating a Unity game into my Flutter application. [This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) package is quite useful for integration. It also provides support for AR kits in Unity.